# What is Sobel operator's order?

Tags: opencv

OpenCV documentation says, (order == 0) means derivative will not applied in this direction, i.e. no calculations for this kernel will be performed.

(Order == 1) means just a simple convolution of image and kernel for this direction.

But what (order == 2) means? How does it affect calculations?

I'm implementing self-written Sobel operator, and it works great for order == 1, but I can't get anything simular to OpenCV's second order Sobel operator, called as cv::Sobel(src, dest, 0, 2, 0).

Comment: I am sorry, i didn't understand ur question ? Do you want to understand what is result of 2nd derivative? or you want to know how it works?

Comment: I guess, the second. I want to know, how is order=1 calculation distinguished from the order=2 one. For order=1 we just take the sum of the kernel applied at every pixel as a new pixel brightness (assuming we're working with a grayscale). What's the major difference with order=2?

Comment: you try applying it twice because when I applied sobel with order=1 twice, I got same result as sobel with order=2...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Order one estimates the first derivative in the specific direction.
Order two estimates the second derivative (the rate of change of the rate of change of intensity). 
And so on.

Think of position (intensity), speed (order = 1), acceleration (order = 2), jerk (rate of change of acceleration - order 3)

Usually higher order derivatives are not too useful, especially due to the discretization of an image and the limited size stencils image operations usually work with.

Applying Sobel first order twice should theoretically give you the second order Sobel, but in practice this is not true due to the discretization of both the image and the Sobel operator.

Comment: Thank you for making it clear. But I still need Sobel order 2 implementation, if dual application does not really work, what does? Found out OpenCV throws an error when order is not less than kernel size, how do they related?

Comment: It's theoretically impossible to determine. For example, to find the rate of change of intensity, you need at least 2 pixels. What does it mean to find the rate of intensity of a single pixel? It will be zero all over if your stencil is only one pixel. Same with second derivative, the acceleration at a point cannot be theoretically estimated (except to estimate all zeros) if you don't have at least a stencil of size 3.

Comment: Oh, of course, it's easy; when one is looking at Sobel operator as at the derivative (which it really is), this thing comes pretty clear because of the derivations nature.